# How to write a unit test for a directive that changes border color in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

how to write correct a test for SetPlateBorderColorDirective? It change border color
my code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appToBorderColor]'
})
export class SetPlateBorderColorDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
  }

  @Input() set appToBorderColor(number: any) {
  
    if (number>0) {
      this.element.nativeElement.style.border = '1px solid green';
    } else if (number==0) {
      this.element.nativeElement.style.border = '1px solid blue';
    } else {
      this.element.nativeElement.style.border = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

My test, by it not work correct:

```
describe('SetPlateBorderColorDirective', ()=>{
  it('', ()=>{
    let creatingDay='1659996000000';
    const mockElementRef: any = {
      nativeElement: {
        'style': 'border: 1px solid grey'
      }
    };
    const directive= new SetPlateBorderColorDirective(mockElementRef);
       let result = directive.appToBorderColor(creatingDay);
       expect(result).toBe('1px solid blue');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the test logging on execution?

Since `1659996000000` is `> 0`, the expected result should be `1px solid green` instead of `1px solid blue`.